# On mcpe, how do you play with your friends on a, say, hunger games server on 0.11.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my cousin want to play a PvP hunger games map on the mobile version (0.11.1) and were wondering how it could be done - we're using Lifeboat Survival Games as a server, but we can't see each other or play together.

Answer (score -1):

Try [sg126.lbsg.net](http://status.lbsg.net/). This is how I fixed the same problem.

If this does not work for you, try it on your friends system, to ensure the problem is not on your side.

If this still does not work, try both connecting to the server at the same time.

The port used is **19132**.

Answer (score -2):

Use  pocketmultiplayer its the best or use the server address on the screen when you are in the map of hunger games there should be a IP there on the screen if not go to lifeboat.com for more information go to lifeboat. Com

Comment: And how would PocketMultiplayer help? You haven't made it clear why it's the best. Your answer isn't really helpful as it stands right now.